# CKeditor does not work on my host!

Tags: ckeditor

Ckeditor was worked on my localhost. When upload to my web host, does not show ckeditor and textarea. How to fix it? Please help me!

Comment: Well, its all javascript, ao it should load. The files may be taking a long time to load, either due to a sloggy server or a slow internet connection. Have you tried reloading a few times ?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this problem, I used ckeditor for drupal, And on my host doesn't work, because my host doesn't allow to execute **jquery.cookie.js**

My solution was to change the name of my file **jquery.cookie.js** and also change the code in "drupal \ modules \ system" in line 1250 where the file is called **jquery.cookie.js**

Comment: Maybe `mod_security` was enabled on the Apache server you tried it with: http://drupal.org/node/522646, https://www.modsecurity.org/tracker/browse/CORERULES-29